# Sonar Jacoco for Kotlin Setup not generating code coverage

Tags: android, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, sonarqube-ops

I'm trying to do Sonar Setup with Jacoco for [Kotlin](https://github.com/arturbosch/sonar-kotlin) to generate Code Coverage report but it's not showing any code coverage. While checking Sonar Console it showing following error. Anyone has faced this issue before, any suggestion what could be miss.

**Meta info**

> plugin using sonarqube version "2.6.1"
>
> gradleVersion = '3.0.1'
>
> kotlinVersion = '1.2.21'
>
> Sonarqube version = Version 6.7.1 (build 35068) - LGPL v3

Frustrating part is, my setup project generating blank code coverage report :(. PFA.

[image]

**Edit :** Please find project structure snap.

I'm adding sonar & Jacoco gradle file setup I'm using to generate sonar-matrix report.

[image]

Here is sonar.gradle file:

```
sonarqube {

    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "jacoco.sonar.test"
        property "sonar.projectName", "Sonar Jacoco Test"
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.1"

        property "sonar.java.source", "7"

        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/outputs/lint-results.xml"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/tmp/kotlin-classes"
        property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/test/,build/tmp/kotlin-classes/devDebugUnitTest"
        property "sonar.tests","src/test/java"
        property "sonar.sources","src/main/java"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths","build/jacoco/testDevDebugUnitTest.exec"
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath","build/test-results/testDevDebugUnitTest"
    }
}
```

and here is jacoco.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.9"
    reportsDir = file("${project.projectDir}/app/build/reports")
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "app:testDevDebugUnitTest") {
    group = "Reporting"

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class',
                      '**/R$*.class',
                      '**/BuildConfig.*',
                      '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                      '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                      '**/*$MembersInjector*.*',
                      '**/Manifest*.*',
                      '**/*Test*.*',
                      'android/**/*.*']

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: "${project.projectDir}/app/build/intermediates/classes/dev",
            excludes: fileFilter
        ) + fileTree(
            dir: "${project.projectDir}/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/devDebug",
            excludes: fileFilter
        )

    // sources
    sourceDirectories = files(["${project.projectDir}/app/src/main/java"])
    executionData = files("${project.projectDir}/app/build/jacoco/testDevDebugUnitTest.exec")
}
```

Following gradle commands I'm using to generate Jacobo report & then soar report.

```
./gradlew clean jacocoTestReport sonarqube
```

**I observed following I'm getting, must be issue some path.**

> Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include
>   debug information into compiled classes?

I'm sorry, if this is looking bit length; but this is best I found to summaries in one place. Please also note I tried similar setup with Java class instead Kotlin it's generating report with code coverage.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include your SonarQube version, please?

Comment: please check the footer of your SonarQube page and add the version you find there. I suspect what you've labeled as your SonarQube version is actually the version of your scanner.

Comment: what version of SonarJava are you using? and which version on Jacoco reports are you generating? SonarJava 5.1 adds jacoco 8.0 support - i am not sure what version you are generating, but this could be maybe related?

Comment: I'm using: SQube: 7.0, SRunner: 3.0.3.778. Jacoco version I have not mentioned explicit and it should be use latest one(i.e. jacoco-0.8.0).

Comment: Where is kotlin source files located?

Comment: It's under man/src/java directory @Andrew.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Could you please review question again, I have added few more information about project setup. FYI: I'm getting same issue.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Do I have to go for this [**detekt**](https://github.com/arturbosch/sonar-kotlin) based solution ??

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm facing the same issue @CoDe

I've found a workaround solution according to your issue: https://android.jlelse.eu/sonarqube-code-coverage-for-kotlin-on-android-with-bitrise-71b2fee0b797

But, is that you wrote the medium article? Actually, I haven't tried it out his workaround yet

Comment: Have you considered using Kover? We switched to it and found it a lot more helpful.

Comment: It's been long, but I'll check. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the android test orchestrator this is likely the problem.

I had the same issue today and after disabling the android test orchestrator the coverage is working again.

Bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72758547

I'm not sure how Android Kotlin builds are configured, but in my Android Java `build.gradle` I had to comment out the test orchestrator like so:

```
android {
...
    testOptions {
        // temporarily disable the orchestrator as this breaks coverage: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72758547
        //execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I'm not using [ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to do to make it work for kotlin.

- Ensure your sonarqube > 7.5
- If your sonarqube ver < 7.5, have the admin install sonar-jacoco plugin. Check the plugin compatibility version if sonarqube < 5.5.

```
plugins {
    id "jacoco"
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7.1"
}
```

Follow this url: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151

Add properties in your build.gradle for it to search for jacoco results.

```
property 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths', "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"
```

Follow this url for properties: https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.5/analysis/analysis-parameters/

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have not same setup now to try this out. But will it be possible for you to create and share repo sample so other can refer and that would be great help.